# how to save highlighted text in tkinter as txt format

Tags: tkinter, save, highlight

I'm trying to save my highlighted text (text widget) as text or CSV but when I save it, the highlight color is gone, any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Neither plain text nor csv supports color information embedded in the text. You'll have to convert your text and colors to a file format that supports color, such as markdown, rst, rtf, etc.

Comment: thanks Bryan, even with converting it is not working. could you check my code is correct for saving Text as txt. `def save_text():
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text.get(1.0,END))`

Comment: Yes, that will save the text in the text widget to a file, though `1.0` should be `”1.0”` and `END` should be `”end-1c”` unless you want an extra newline that tkinter adds to text widgets.